# Broken side-by-side comparison in revision page when a Youtube video is included and rendered

Tags: bug, status-completed, revisions-list, diff

I came across this post and decided to [check its revision](https://space.stackexchange.com/posts/8310/revisions) (to explore the source code for the YouTube video).

If we choose a view then refresh, then the views show up correctly, except for the side-by-side view:

[image]

---

If we start with markdown view, then switch to inline view, the view is missing the change which comes after the video (please refer to the side-by-side view above):

[image]

If we switch over to side-by-side view, it is empty:

[image]

---

This bug also cause an extra copy of the inline view to be appended whenever we switch between side-by-side view, then back to inline.

Comment: inb4 update your Flash player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is (mostly) fixed now. <s>Diffs of YouTube videos are still somewhat problematic and ugly</s>, but at least it's mostly correct now and especially doesn't break the page anymore.

Update: With the [move to the HTML5 player](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10676/embed-youtube-videos-using-the-html5-player/10709#10709), I also made YouTube videos look right in narrower columns, so they now render correctly in the side-by-side diffs.